# Why does Map have a return statement in this example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Learning React and trying to cheat off this [codepen](https://codepen.io/JiaYuisalolicon/pen/xYjwyE?editors=0010). I do not understand 2 things about the map function in FormCard.

1. Why does this .map function have a `return` statement, I did not see a return on other examples
2. Why does the arrow function use curly braces instead of parentheses like the previous arrow function

const FormCard = (props) => (

```
  const FormCard = (props) => (
  <div>
    {
      DATA.map((props) => {
        return <div style={{...largebox, ...flex}} key={props.id}>
          <div style={{...Photo,backgroundImage: `url(${props.photo})`}}></div>
          <div>
            <Author author={props.author}/>
            <Something bio={props.bio}/>
            <AdBox adpic={props.adpic} />
            <IconBox />
          </div>
      </div>
      })
    }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: All `map` callbacks have a return statement. Those who doesn't are probably using the **impicit `return`** of the arrow functions.

Comment: Hints: Read [Arrow function](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) chapter.

Comment: There's really no good reason. On the contrary, the code you posted uses a very inconsistent style.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are two different ways of returning from arrow functions.

The implicit return:

If the body starts with an expression and not with a `{` is seen as a value to be returned.

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(v => ({value:v})); // gives an array of objects with value set to v. 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(v => v*v)// gives an array of squares of the initial array.
```

the explicit return:

If the body starts with a `{`, it seen as the body of the function, and a `return` statement is expected to return.

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(v => { return {value:v}}); // gives an array of objects with value set to v. 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(v => { return v*v})// gives an array of squares of the initial array.
```

Comment: this answer makes the relevant distinction for flavors of arrow functions: expressions vice functions.

Answer (score 4):

Generally,

```
array.map((arg) => { return actionWith(arg) })
array.map((arg) => actionWith(arg))
```

Are equal, thus developers shrink their functions if they have returns only